# What is the right way to use access a value in an enumeration in C++

Tags: c++, enums, mingw

I have come across this while coding and I am not sure about why its the way It is.
Consider this code

### Case 1

```
#include<iostream>

enum test{
a,b,c,d,e,f
};

int main(){
    std::cout << a;
    return 0x1;
}
```

### Case 2

```
#include<iostream>

enum test{
a,b,c,d,e,f
};

int main(){
    std::cout << test::a;
    return 0x1;
}
```

Why does the code compile and execute properly for both? Is using `test::` not necessary while using enumerations?

Comment: The moment you declare a variable 'a' in your scope, there is a difference. Try adding `int a = 42;`

Comment: @JVApen, I did exactly that and it doesn't throw an error if I do `std::cout << a;` which I think isn't nice as it can cause confusions, so I think I will stick to using `test::` to make it clear to future me reading my code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `test::` is not neccessary, because `enum test` declares an *unscoped* enum. `test::` would become neccessary when you define a *scoped* enum like this:

```
enum class test {...};
```

See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum for more detailed information.